# Why aren't entries in PATH in the order I put them and why does PATH have duplicates?

Tags: linux, bash

In my `.bashrc` I have the following:

```
export TOPDIR=/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64
export KSRC=/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/arch/x86/include/uapi/asm/:/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/include:/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/include/config
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/include
export KERNEL_BUILD_PATH=/lib/modules/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/build/
```

But when I do `echo $PATH`from the command-line, I get the following output:

```
bash-4.4$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/include:/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/include/config:/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/arch/x86/include/uapi/asm/:/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/include:/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/include/config
```

There are two issues here about which I would seek expert opinion from this panel:

1. The order in which I have entered my paths in my `.bashrc` as appended values for my `PATH` variable does not reflect in the command output. I had specified the order in my `.bashrc` to force the compiler to look for a specific system file in the order of the paths entered.
2. There is duplication of paths in the output.

I would like to know what is causing these issues and how can I resolve these?

Comment: Looks like something else is adding extra entries before .bashrc runs. Actually, .bashrc normally isn't run for login shells, only things like subshells. Check for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, `~/.profile, and maybe /etc/profile, and see if any of those is doing it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes discovered that /etc/profile has a function pathmunge() which modifies the PATH variable resulting in the duplicity